# QML formatting text in TextEdit

Tags: textfield, qml, text-editor

I'm new to QML, I'm trying to create text editor where you can format text to make it bold, italic, underlined, justification etc. basically I want this to act as general text editor ( LibreOffice Writer or other ) 
Next step is to convert formatted text in TextEdit field to HTML code, so if text in field is bold then `<B>...</B>` is added to text, etc.

I managed to create this kind of editor in GDK using text buffer and tags but I don't know where to start with QML.

Comment: You might want to take a look at one of the examples provided with Qt5 called "text" in your Qt5.X install directory : `5.1.0/clang_64/examples/quick/controls/text/`

Answer (score 0):

You can still use tags for formatting text inside a `TextEdit` Element, as shown in the [documentation](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qml-textedit.html#details).